# Infinite closed shift-invariant set of binary sequences with zero entropy?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

Does there exist an infinite closed shift-invariant $X \subset \{0,1\}^\Bbb Z$ with zero topological entropy?
How to think of an example?
Will periodic points of shift$|_X$ have zero entropy?

Answer (score 1):

The set
$$
   X_k := \{x: \text{there are at most $k$ occurrences of $1$ in $x$}\}
$$
(for any $k\geq 1$) is shift-invariant and closed, and has topological entropy $0$.  It is clearly infinite, though only countably infinite.

If you prefer an uncountably infinite set, recall that the entropy of a shift space $X$ is really "average entropy per position".  So, you can still have infinite amount of information in your sequence spread enough in such a way that the average amount of information per position is $0$.

To construct an example, for a non-decreasing function $g:\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}^+$, let
$$
   X_{g(\cdot)}:= \{x: \text{for each $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, the number of $1$s in $x|_{[i,i+n)}$ is at most $g(n)$}\} \;.
$$
Now, choose $g(\cdot)$ such that

- $g(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ (so that $X_{g(\cdot)}$ is uncountable: exercise!), but
- $\log\sum_{k\leq g(n)}\binom{n}{k}=o(n)$ as $n\to\infty$.  (This means, the number of possible words of length $n$ appearing on a sequence $x\in X_{g(\cdot)}$ is asymptotically negligible compared to $2^n$.)

Choosing $g(n):=\lfloor\log (n+1)\rfloor$ or $g(n):=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ would certainly do.

Comment: Thank you. What abt the set of all periodic points?

Comment: What about the set of periodic points?  If you mean the exponential growth rate of the number of periodic points in $X$, then that is also $0$ if the entropy of $X$ is $0$.  Namely, in general, if $P_n(X)$ denotes the set of periodic points with period $n$, then $|P_n(X)|$ is bounded by the number of words of length $n$ appearing in $X$, and hence $\limsup_n\frac{\log|P_n(X)|}{n}\leq h(X)$.