# Symbolic Dynamics - Infinite Shift Space of Finite Type with Entropy 0

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

The exercise asks to find a **infinite shift space of finite type with entropy $\mathbf{0}$**.

(If our alphabet is a finite set $\mathcal{A}$, a shift space of finite type is a closed subset of the full shift space of sequences of $\mathcal{A}$, that can be described as a subset of sequences which doesn't contain strings from some **finite set of forbidden strings**.)

I can think of a infinite shift space of finite type, with entropy $0$, which is not of finite type (which is also found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346674/infinite-closed-shift-invariant-set-of-binary-sequences-with-zero-entropy)): take the alphabet to be $\{a,b\}$, and the shift space to be all bi-infinite sequences with one single $b$ surrounded by all $a$'s - it is a closed set, satisfying that the number of possible strings of length $n$ is $n+1$, and therefore the entropy is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n} =  0$$
But I couldn't think of an example of a finite type, please help.

Comment: For a topological Markov chain, it suffices to consider one that has only fixed points. In other words, the transition matrix can be the identity.

Comment: @JohnB: it has entropy $0$, but is not infinite.

Comment: I mean of course an infinite identity matrix...

Comment: @JohnB: the alphabet must be finite (I will edit the question). If this statement has no connection to what you said, then I didn't understand you :)

Comment: I see, now I understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, had to leave, answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The simplest example occurs for two symbols.

Consider the $2\times2$ transition matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
(or its transpose).
The spectral radius is $1$ but the corresponding topological Markov chain has infinitely many sequences.

You can obtain many other examples of a similar type: think of a graph that after a while gets pushed into a fixed symbol.

Comment: Is it a shift of finite type?

Comment: Sure, "topological Markov chain"="shift of finite type". The forbidden string in this case is $ba$ if you take the symbols $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Oh, OK. Am I right in saying that the shift space you've described is composed of all sequences of the form $...aaaabbbbbb...$, where the index of the letter change is arbitrary, plus the two sequences of all $a$'s and all $b$'s?

Comment: Yes, exactly those sequences.

Comment: Great - for all $n$ there are $n+1$ allowed words of length $n$, so the entropy is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n} = 0$$Thank you very much John B!